# Treat binary data as a file object?

Tags: python, file-io

In this code snippet (authored by another person), `self.archive` is a path to a large file and `raw_file` is the contents of the file read as binary data.

```
with open(self.archive, "rb") as f:
    f.seek(offset)
    raw_file = start + f.read(dlen - len(start))
    ...
    f.write(raw_file)
```

This archive file contains stored image files, and I'd like to access them `pygame.image.load` which requires a File object. But I need to do something like `pygame.image.load(toVirtualFileObject(raw_file))` (i.e. access this archive file's contents as File objects without writing to disk first).

Can this be done?

Comment: You could use any file-like object, for example `StringIO`; but if its a few MB, you might exhaust the available memory as doing so will load the file into memory at once. What is the problem with writing to disk and reading it?

Comment: Strange rules? Typically such extracting is done as part of the install process - which is why programs with a heavy asset library take up a lot of disk space, and take a while to install as well (think MMORPGs). @jwodder pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, the joys of copy protection :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is what [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) (in Python 2) and [`io.BytesIO`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) in (in Python 3) are for.

Comment: I got this from google which explains the above statement - `BytesIO` is a class in Python's `io` module that provides a file-like interface for in-memory byte streams. You can think of `BytesIO` as a convenient way to manipulate binary data in memory, without the need for actual files.
NOTE - to work with any file-handling library file-like object will be required and io library provides that.