# Sending larger than 5GB dataframe to S3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm attempting to upload a dataframe to S3. The dataframe is created by sourcing several data sources and joining them together in addition to performing a few transformation. The operations are done fully in memory. I also need to store the data into `s3` where each line is a `json` record as such:

```
{"key_1": "value_11", "key_2": "value_12", ...}
{"key_1": "value_21", "key_2": "value_22", ...}
...
```

I was using `put_object()` and had no issue until the tables got larger.

**Code Snippet**

```
...

json_buffer = StringIO()
df_copy.to_json(json_buffer, orient="records", lines=True)
json_buffer.seek(0)

# self.__s3.put_object(
#     Bucket=bucket, 
#     Body=json_buffer.getvalue(), 
#     Key=key_json)

GB = 1024 ** 3
# Ensure that multipart uploads only happen if the size of a transfer
# is larger than S3's size limit for nonmultipart uploads, which is 5 GB.
upl_config = TransferConfig(multipart_threshold=5*GB)

self.__s3.upload_fileobj(
    json_buffer,
    Bucket=bucket, 
    Key=key_json,
    Config=upl_config)
```

With the above code I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

I've tried the following approaches:

- [raise ValueError('Fileobj must implement read')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57451656/raise-valueerrorfileobj-must-implement-read)
- [Saving file like object to s3 i get error: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66902713/saving-file-like-object-to-s3-i-get-error-unicode-objects-must-be-encoded-befor/66902759#66902759)

**Question:**
Is there anyway to save the data as `json` records and not a `csv` like the other question?

Comment: 5 gigabytes (GB) - Fixed typo

Comment: I would expect to use BytesIO, not StringIO, since upload_fileobj is documented as only operating on bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to pass in a buffer of bytes not str. try using BytesIO instead of StringIO.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_fileobj